# How to set an alias to "count" property on OdataV4 json result

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to set an allias to "count" property in odata,
here is my query;

```
/odata/DersAcilans?$expand=derskayits($count=true;$top=0)
```

This query give this json result;

[image]

"DersKayits@odata.count" propery name is not fits me,
How can set an alias for this propery in asp.net core odata?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to refer the following code to rename the property name:

```
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    var conf = odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
    conf.EntityType.Property(c => c.Name).Name = "Student_Name";  //change the Property name from Name to Student_Name
```

Details sample code as below:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            routeBuilder.Select().Filter();
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
        }); 
    }

    IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var conf = odataBuilder.EntitySet<Student>("Students");
        conf.EntityType.Property(c => c.Name).Name = "Student_Name";  

        return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Code in the Model:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the result as below (reference [this sample](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)):

[image]

Comment: For my entity property names, this will work. But how can i make it for "count" ?

Comment: "DersKayits@odata.count" name comes defaultly from odatav4 when i type  : $count=true;

Comment: @ahmetsse, I also has same scenario. Do you have any solution ?

Comment: @karunakarbhogyari unfortunately still a problem for me